# Radio Options and Buttons not Showing their value after clicking Add Button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, list, radio-button

I'm confused as to why my radio options and Important/Unimportant Buttons are not showing a value of grocery, work, chores, finance; or important/unimportant when added to my task list as a list item. The other input values of task name, description, date etc. show up, so I'm not sure where the error is in the code, or if I am missing some additional required JS code. Any advice would be appreciated.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3fa24whe/2/

```
Category:
      <input type="radio" id="Grocery" name="category" value="Grocery" class="category">
        <label for="grocery">Grocery</label>
        <input type="radio" id="work" name="category" value="Work" class="category">
        <label for="work">Work</label>
        <input type="radio" id="chores" name="category" value="Chores" class="category">
        <label for="chores">Chores</label>
        <input type="radio" id="finance" name="category" value="Finance" class="category">
        <label for="finance">Finance</label>
      <br>
      <br>
      
     <div class="importance" id="importance"> 
   <div class="btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary importance" class="importance"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" value="important" name="important"></span> Important</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary importance" class="importance" value="unimportant" name="unimportant"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span> Unimportant</button>
  </div>
    </div>
```

```
//Take Text Input and Add <li> to To Do List
 $addButton.on("click", function(){
  
  //Creating object Variables 
  var $sort = $(".sort").val();
  var $newTask = $(".newTask").val();
  var $taskDescr = $(".taskDescr").val();
  var $taskDate = $(".taskDate").val();
  var $category= $(".category").val();
  var $importance = $("btn.importance").val();
  var $newTaskString = $sort + "  , " + $taskDescr + " , " + $newTask + "  , " + $taskDate + "  , " + $category + " , " + $importance + " , "; 
  var $todoList = $(".uncompleted");
```

Comment: If you look at the console in the jsfiddle you will notice that you haven't included jquery

Comment: Thank you - I used jquery-1.11.0.min.js and bootstrap in my code, but can't find those options in the jsfiddle

Comment: On jsfiddle on the javascript section just above line 1 you can see an option to add jquery or other libraries

Comment: Thank you - I tried to add them, not sure if it worked! Updated the jsfiddle link..these are my libraries just in case: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rock+Salt|Raleway:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>